# Change class when window's width is less than 1025

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse " role="navigation">
        <!--
            stuff
        -->
  </nav>
```

I want to change the class attribute to 'navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse', if window's size is lower than 1025px.
Like this:

```
<nav class="navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse " role="navigation">
            <!--
                stuff
            -->
</nav>
```

I tried this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rzdGJ/1/)

It didnt worked out for me.

Comment: what didn't work out exactly? you either didn't register the event correctly or something in your css is messed up . write down your code here so we can take a look

Comment: Demo works fine but doesn't have anything to do with your navbar. Provide a [mcve] that is representattive of your specific problem and code

Comment: looks like your jsfiddle works to me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript to change the class, can you change the css to use the @media selectors?

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvmh5bxb/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) event listener to listen for changes for when the css media query match and don't match instead of listening on every px resize.

```
matchMedia("(max-width: 1025px)").addListener(evt => 
  $('nav').toggleClass('collapse', evt.matches)
)
```